# How do I update the primary email address used by my Apple ID when using Find My iDevice?

Tags: icloud, email, apple-id

I have an Apple ID that I use for both the App/iTunes Stores and for iCloud. Because I originally created it years ago, it's an email address I no longer use, let's call it `dan@old.com`. I would like to replace it with `dan@new.com`.

This is easy enough to do from the Manage My Apple ID web interface, however when I change the address and attempt to update my iPhone and iPad I hit a snag: in order to Sign Out of my Apple ID in iCloud Settings, I must first provide my Find My iDevice credentials, since that prevents a thief from simply punting me out of my device were they to steal it.

The problem is, it asks for the Apple ID password for `dan@old.com`, and when I enter that, it fails (with the incredibly helpful message "there was a server error"). I have to assume this failure is because that combination of email address and password is no longer part of my Apple ID.

Can someone provide me with a sane, step-by-step way to change my primary Apple ID email address from one email that I control to another, given the use of iCloud and Find My iDevice on multiple devices?

Comment: http://support.apple.com/kb/ts5223

Comment: or, If you haven't made the change yet, turn off findmyiphone first, then make the change, then turn it back on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Tyson says, this might help: http://support.apple.com/kb/ts5223

If you can make your AppleID change back to dan@old.com you should then be able to sign out of it on the iDevices. After signing out the iDevices - change the AppleID again to dan@new.com and you're good to go.

The place to change your AppleID (which is used by iCloud and iTunes and the Mac App Store) information is at https://appleid.apple.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the `dan@old.com` email as a secondary email address for your Apple ID and try signing out then. If you feel the need to you can then remove it once again. You can do this at [appleid.apple.com](http://appleid.apple.com)

Answer (score -1):

All you have to do is sign out your old primary Apple I'd and sign in with your new one